# Is max-device-width referring to document.body.clientWidth?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries

In media queries, I've seen `max-width`, `min-width`,  `max-device-width` and `min-device-width` and `orientation`.

From a JavaScript standpoint, are these referring to `document.body.clientWidth`? Or `window.outerWidth` ? Also I see there is `document.body.offsetWidth`.

Is there a resource out there that list out all the valid css media query parameters along with what JavaScript attributes that match up with them?

Comment: also this page looks useful to you http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Answer (score 13):

So, you want a list of all the valid css media query parameters equivalent in JavaScript.

Let's try to do it, relying on the  [media queries W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

---

## Media types

It doesn't seem to be possible to retrieve the media type (screen, print, etc) [directly with a JavaScript property/method](http://lists.apple.com/archives/web-dev/2006/Sep/msg00000.html), so you must rely on workarounds, scripts or plugins.

I've found:

1. **[matchMedia polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/matchMedia.js)** seems the best solution (used by Modernizr and Respond.js too)
2. [CSS media detection script](http://cssmedia.pemor.pl/) (seems oldish)
3. [jMediaType](http://code.google.com/p/jmediatype/) (still relies on css)

---

## Media Features (directly detectable)

#### 1. width

`window.innerWidth` / `document.body.clientWidth` / `document.documentElement.clientWidth` (see below)

#### 2. height

`window.innerHeight` / `document.body.clientHeight` / `document.documentElement.clientHeight` (see below)

#### 3. device-width

`screen.width`

#### 4. device-height

`screen.height`

#### 5. orientation

`window.orientation` (see below)

#### 6. color

`screen.colorDepth`

#### 7. resolution

`screen.pixelDepth` / `window.devicePixelRatio` (see below)

---

## Media Features (detected indirectly)

#### 1. width / height

Given the differences between browsers, you need a function to get `width` and `height`. Some time ago i found this snippet (can't remember where) that works cross-browser:

```
var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var width = w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;

var height = w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
```

#### 2. aspect-ratio

> the ratio of the value of the ‘width’ media feature to the value of
>   the ‘height’ media feature

`width` / `height` (see above)

#### 3. device-aspect-ratio

> the ratio of the value of the ‘device-width’  to the value of the ‘device-height’

`screen.width` / `screen.height`

#### 4. resolution

> the density of the pixels of the output device. The ‘dpi’ and ‘dpcm’
>   units describe the resolution of an output device, i.e., the density
>   of device pixels.

So it's not the screen size (width x height) as many think!

```
var resolution = window.devicePixelRatio||screen.pixelDepth||screen.colorDepth;
```

`screen.pixelDepth` is for Firefox only, and you can find `window.devicePixelRatio` compatibility [on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/06/devicepixelrati.html).

[Here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml) i read that `screen.colorDepth` is ok as a fallback.

#### 5. monochrome

> the number of bits per pixel in a monochrome frame buffer. If the
>   device is not a monochrome device, the output device value will be 0

```
if ( screen.colorDepth == 2) {
    var monochrome = /* retrieve resolution here, see above */;
}else{
    var monochrome = 0;
}
```

#### 6. orientation

> is ‘portrait’ when the value of the ‘height’ media feature is greater
>   than or equal to the value of the ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise
>   ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

```
if ( width > height ) {
    var orientation = 'landscape';
}else{
    var orientation  = 'potrait';
}
```

The **`window.orientation`** property is not supported by all browsers, and it returns a numeric value, so it's not directly related to *orientation* as intended by W3C. Check [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript) for more information.

---

## Media Features (undetectable)

I couldn't find a way to detect the following media features with JavaScript (and i don't think it's possible):

- color-index
- scan
- grid

---

## More intresting stuff

- `screen.availHeight` = height of the screen minus interface features (such as the taskbar)
- `screen.availWidth` = width of the screen minus interface features (such as the taskbar)
- To emulate media queries with JavaScript there's [Modernizr's mq() method](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq), but be aware: if a browser doesn't support media queries it <s>won't execute the code at all</s> will always return *false*.

---

## Sources

1. width/height : http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow
2. device-width/height : http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/
3. orientation : [Detect rotation of Android phone in the browser with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript)
4. resolution and color related stuff : http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml
5. monochrome : [Javascript: detect monochrome display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461336/javascript-detect-monochrome-display)
6. pixel ratio : http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/06/devicepixelrati.html

Answer (score 0):

The min-width: and max-width: queries refer to the logical window (whose size varies as the user changes the size of the browser's window), while the min-device-width: and max-device-width (and orientation:) queries refer to the physical screen/viewport (whose size does not change once the "meta...viewport..." statement has fixed it).

Depending on what your goal and audience are, you might find an alternative approach better suited than Media Queries. You may find it helpful to peruse http://www.ckollars.org/alternative-to-media-queries.html